# Email Sender Image from Google+ Account

Tags: email, google-plus, apple-mail, google-inbox

I'd like for all emails send from my server (e.g. mail@example.com) to arrive in recipients inboxes with a custom sender image used in Apple Mail and Google Inbox.

I have created a new Google+ account, linked and verified my website (by uploading the .html file, you know ;]), but still, the emails don't contain my Google + profile image as their sender image.

I assume it's something to do with me not sending emails from the new gmail address I've created with Google+. I'm hoping someone knows how to work around this and have Google+ treat any emails coming from my domain as the new Google+ account's own.

Comment: You are going to have to be more specific about how you are sending the emails and what headers you are including in them.

Comment: I am sending the emails via CodeIgniter 3's Email Class (using default settings except for 'mailtype' set to 'html') http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: @SolidI Is your email authenticated? If your Google + account is linked to example.com, you may need to authenticate your email with example.com SPF/DKIM signature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This Article](http://freshinbox.com/blog/how-to-get-your-logo-to-display-in-gmail-grid-view/) seems to provide a good overall answer. I'll do a quick summary here.

As a takeaway:

- Ensure your site is verified on Google+. This is done in Webmaster tools[(link)](https://support.google.com/business/answer/4569085?rd=1), and your webmaster must approve.
- Ensure you have adequate email traffic (seems around 1k a week should do it).
- When sending from a domain not matching Google+, you'll need to include a snippet of code in your email, and have Gmail approve the link.
- Ensure that your email is authenticated against your domain and not your ESPs (or use the Featured Image markup).