# Image next to Contact name in Google's Inbox

Tags: google-inbox

When receiving emails in Google's Inbox, usually you get as image a coloured circle with the first letter of the contact's mail.

But in rare occasions, there will be an image placeholder, like for instance the example I paste for YouTube. (I know YouTube is owned by Google, but I have seen many other examples)

Is it possible for me to make my own address to have its own image, when someone received an email in Inbox? If so, how?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

In Short, this is because you likely don't have a Google+ page with a linked domain matching your email address.

The longer version: [Link is here...](http://freshinbox.com/blog/how-to-get-your-logo-to-display-in-gmail-grid-view/)

EDIT: Seems like this is not a popular answer...

Here's a fuller version:
This Article seems to provide a good overall answer. I'll do a quick summary here.

As a takeaway:

- Ensure your site is verified on Google+. This is done in Webmaster tools(link), and your webmaster must approve.
- Ensure you have adequate email traffic (seems around 1k a week should do it).
- When sending from a domain not matching Google+, you'll need to include a snippet of code in your email, and have Gmail approve the link.
- Ensure that your email is authenticated against your domain and not your ESPs (or use the Featured Image markup).

This questions is related: [Email Sender Image from Google+ Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106816/email-sender-image-from-google-account/33174864#33174864)