# Is there any way to set email profile picture using MailMessage in C# or any similar methods that may do that?

Tags: c#, console-application

I've made a very simple C# -based console application which sends email to the email receiver specified using `MailMessage.To`.

But I just couldn't find any resources on how to add or set up an email profile picture using C#.

Is there any way to do so by using C#?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by *"email profile picture"*?

Comment: What is an email profile picture?

Comment: Consider using http://en.gravatar.com/

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @AlexK . Something like [this](https://ibb.co/cP64RU)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean someting like profile picture in Google email view I believe the profile picture is not a part of an email.

It's retrieved from your profile by Gmail when it displays the email and the result depends on whether you have the right settings for your profile.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33174864/1324602) for more info.